# Working with Windows Indexing and PHP

Tags: php, windows, indexing, adodb

I'm trying to get the Windows Indexing search work directly over PHP so I can search for text inside thousands of files very quickly.

I have it working on Visual Basic with this script:

```
'To run this snippet, save it to a file and run it using cscript.exe from a command line. 
'Running the .vbs file with Windows Script Host may cause dialog boxes to open for each item returned from the index.

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/folderIndexed' AND CONTAINS('myDemo') ORDER BY System.ItemName DESC", objConnection

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemName")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Now I'm trying to port it into PHP by using the [COM class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63325b03-18f9-4506-a896-958ce55bde8a/query-windows-indexing-server-with-php?forum=sqldriverforphp) but I'm getting this error message:

> com_exception
>   **Source:** Unknown
>   **Description:** Unknown

My attempt looks like so:

```
<?php
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn->Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");

$recordset = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");  

$keyword = 'a';
$sql = "SELECT filename, size, path
     FROM SCOPE()
     WHERE  DIRECTORY='file:C:/folderIndexed' and CONTAINS('a')";


//-----------------> line of the error <-----------------
$recordset = $recordset->Open($sql, $conn);


foreach ($recordset as $obj) { 
    echo  $obj->Fields->Item("System.filename")->Value,  "\ n" ;  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using PHP 5.5. and I'm using `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` at **php.ini**. The php_com_dotnet.dll file is placed at the `ext` folder as detailed at the `extension_dir` value.

---

**Related question:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727902/empty-com-object-for-adodb-connection-with-php

Comment: i am not sure but the msdn doc says `Always use 3rd arg to COM() constructor.`

Comment: @Nouphal.M I don't see it. In fact, the two other parameters are optionals : `COM::COM ( string $module_name [, mixed $server_name [, int $codepage [, string $typelib ]]] )` and you can see the example `$obj = new COM("Application.ID")` [here](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php).

Comment: check here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63325b03-18f9-4506-a896-958ce55bde8a/query-windows-indexing-server-with-php?forum=sqldriverforphp

Comment: @Nouphal.M still having the exact same problem after changing it to `new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF8) `

Comment: Is the error created by the creation of the com object (first line) or one of the following operations (you can check by commenting out)?

Comment: Updated question. (its in this line `$recordset = $recordset->Open($sql, $conn);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$recordset->open` does not return a RecordSet, you should not be assigning the return value as you are doing.

Try changing:

```
$recordset = $recordset->Open($sql, $conn);
```

To

```
$recordset->Open($sql, $conn);
```

In addition, your ported code significantly deviates from structure of your VBScript version. Here is my attempt at porting your code, which works for me.

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$recordset = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");  

$conn->Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");

// your query doesn't work for me in VBSCRIPT or PHP. this one does.
$recordset->Open("SELECT Top 5 System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX", $conn);

if(!$recordset->EOF) $recordset->MoveFirst();
while(!$recordset->EOF) {
    echo $recordset->Fields->Item("System.ItemPathDisplay")->Value . "\n";
    $recordset->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin!! The Main problem was on the query, I was not using `SYSTEMINDEX` and neither valid `fields` for the select, now I'm using  `"SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM  SYSTEMINDEX  WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/xmls/folder1' AND CONTAINS('a')"` plus the change you mentioned and your looping through the records.

Comment: In case you know more about the topic, I will open a new question regarding the "limit" or "maxRecords" for the query under the same tags. :)

Comment: Here it is the related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832267/set-a-limit-maxrecords-property-for-windows-indexing-search-through-php-com

Comment: If there are no resutls I get this error in the line where `$recordSet->MoveFirst()` is: `<b>Source:</b> ADODB.Recordset<br/><b>Description:</b> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.`

Comment: I have edited my answer to add an additional EOF check.