# Set a limit / maxRecords property for Windows Indexing Search through PHP COM

Tags: php, windows, indexing, adodb

I'm using Windows Indexing search together with PHP to search inside thousands of files.

I got it working by using the [PHP COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) class:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$recordset = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");

$conn - > Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");


$recordset - > Open("SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM  SYSTEMINDEX  WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/xxxx/' AND CONTAINS('xxxx')", $conn);

$recordset - > MoveFirst();

while (!$recordset - > EOF) {
    echo $recordset - > Fields - > Item("System.ItemName") - > Value."\n";
    $recordset - > MoveNext();
}
```

Now I would like to use the [maxRecords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property as used in Visual Basic to deal with ADO.

```
//Visual Basic usage of the property
objRecordSet.MaxRecords = 150
```

I don't know if there's any equivalent for the COM class in PHP and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$recordset = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
$recordset->MaxRecords = 150;
```

PHP's COM class is just a wrapper around COM in general (I think OLE Automation to be specific), and for the most part if a property or function is exposed to VBScript, it can be translated into PHP code directly.

Comment: You are a genius on this matter my friend! :D

Comment: Another related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835330/change-system-datemodified-format-on-windows-search