# Change System.DateModified format on Windows Search

Tags: windows, indexing, adodb, windows-search

I'm using Windows Indexing search together with PHP to search inside thousands of files.

I got it working by using the PHP COM class:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$recordset = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");

$conn - > Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");


$recordset - > Open("SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM  SYSTEMINDEX  WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/xxxx/' AND CONTAINS('xxxx')", $conn);

$recordset - > MoveFirst();

while (!$recordset - > EOF) {
    echo $recordset - > Fields - > Item("System.ItemName") - > Value."\n";
    $recordset - > MoveNext();
}
```

I am retrieving the `DateModified` field of each element and I've realized the format of it depends on the System configuration. It is possible to set it through the control panel in Windows.

I am wondering if there's any way to get it in the desired format in order to avoid having to change it by using the control panel in every system I want to run the script.

I noticed [the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the property `formatAs` but I'm not sure how to change it and the documentation is not very complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a VT_DATE object into a UNIX timestamp with [variant_date_to_timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.variant-date-to-timestamp.php) and then format it with [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), this should work regardless of the date format in the control panel.

```
$format = "Y-m-d";
$object = $recordset->Fields->Item("System.DateModified")->Value;
$timestamp = variant_date_to_timestamp($object);
echo date($format, $timestamp) . "\n";
```

Comment: I'm getting the wrong modified date. The returned timestamp is incorrect. I opened a new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059452/getting-wrong-value-for-variant-date-to-timestamp