# Getting wrong value for variant_date_to_timestamp() function

Tags: php, adodb, windows-search

In relation with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835330/change-system-datemodified-format-on-windows-search), I'm getting a wrong value for the the modified date when querying the windows ADODB connection for indexing files.

This is the line or the query:

```
$recordset - > Open("SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM  SYSTEMINDEX  WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/xxxx/' AND CONTAINS('xxxx')", $conn);
```

I've getting good results on localhost (php 5.5.6), but not in other servers (php 5.5.8). I'm getting the wrong `timestamp` value and therefore it converts it into a wrong date when I use PHP functions to create my customized format:

```
date_default_timezone_set(ini_get('date.timezone'));

$date = $recordset->Fields->Item("System.DateModified")->Value;
$timestamp = variant_date_to_timestamp($date);  //getting a wrong date here

$file['date'] => date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

There's a different of some hours between the expected result and the result I'm getting. (2 hours)

It seems to be related with the [`variant_date_to_timestamp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.variant-date-to-timestamp.php) function of PHP.
I've already set the proper `date.timezone` in the *php.ini* file and added the `date_default_timezone_set` call before calling  `variant_date_to_timestamp`.

I'm using **PHP 5.5.8.**

I've found a [similar problem/bug commented on 2004](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29258). It talks about the two hours difference as well. I find it difficult to believe it hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: Can you print the result of ini_get('date.timezone') from each server, and date_default_timezone_get() immediately before your date() command? I suspect the timezone is different between the servers.

Comment: I've set the correct timezone for each server. And yeah, it is different. But I still getting different results than the ones displayed for the windows explorer, which is also configured under the same timezone.

Comment: I get `Europe/Berlin` for both cases.

Comment: Does echoing the current timestamp also show a 2 hour offset?

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven yeah. It does. Even the PHP `date.timezone` is set correctly and the `ini_get('date.timezone')` return the correct value. Why is it?

Comment: The server date and time settings are also set properly.

Comment: It's been a few years, but I believe I dealt with something similar, if not the same, using ADODB. For some reason, the variant_date_to_timestamp function was returning incorrect timestamps. I ended up using variant_set_type($variant, VT_BSTR) to get a string representation of the date. This can be used for most variant types PHP doesn't handle.